# Can pyarrow write multiple parquet files to a folder like fastparquet's file_scheme='hive' option?

Tags: python, hadoop, parquet, pyarrow

I have a multi-million record SQL table that I'm planning to write out to many parquet files in a folder, using the pyarrow library.  The data content seems too large to store in a single parquet file.

However, I can't seem to find an API or parameter with the pyarrow library that allows me to specify something like:

```
file_scheme="hive"
```

As is supported by the fastparquet python library.

Here's my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

conn_str = 'UID=username;PWD=passwordHere;' + 
    'DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVERNAME=myConfig;DATABASE=myDB'

#----> Query the SQL database into a Pandas dataframe
conn = pyodbc.connect( conn_str, autocommit=False)
sql = "SELECT * FROM ClientAccount (NOLOCK)"
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, conn)


#----> Convert the dataframe to a pyarrow table and write it out
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, './clients/' )
```

This throws an error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyarrow/parquet.py", line 912, in write_table
    os.remove(where)
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: './clients/'
```

If I replace that last line with the following, it works fine but writes only one big file:

```
pq.write_table(table, './clients.parquet' )
```

Any ideas how I can do the multi-file output thing with pyarrow?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to partition the data being written wiht pyarrow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset` https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/parquet.py#L938.

I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1858 about adding some more documentation about this.

I recommend seeking support for Apache Arrow on the mailing list dev@arrow.apache.org. Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean there is an option to write partitioned data? I took a look at the parquet.py and do not see anything related to partitions in the write function.

Comment: @Drew yes, the `write_to_dataset` function, but it is undocumented yet. https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/9c7e06b2e520137906f078df185b3a03e674e07d/python/pyarrow/parquet.py#L1013