# Pyarrow s3fs partition by timestamp

Tags: python, pyarrow

Is it possible to use a timestamp field in the `pyarrow` table to partition the `s3fs` file system by "`YYYY/MM/DD/HH`" while writing parquet file to `s3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to achieve with a pyarrow write_to_dataset function which allows you to specify partition columns to create subdirectories.

Example:

```
import os
import s3fs
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pyarrow.filesystem import S3FSWrapper

access_key = <access_key>
secret_key = <secret_key>
bucket_name = <bucket_name>

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=access_key, secret=secret_key)

bucket_uri = 's3://{0}/{1}'.format(bucket_name, "data")

data = {'date': ['2018-03-04T14:12:15.653Z', '2018-03-03T14:12:15.653Z', '2018-03-02T14:12:15.653Z', '2018-03-05T14:12:15.653Z'],
        'battles': [34, 25, 26, 57],
        'citys': ['london', 'newyork', 'boston', 'boston']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'battles', 'citys'])
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"))
df['year'], df['month'], df['day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year), df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month), df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
df.groupby(by=['citys'])
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, bucket_uri, filesystem=fs, partition_cols=['year', 'month', 'day'], use_dictionary=True,  compression='snappy', use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)
```

Comment: `write_to_dataset` is not yet documented in http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html -- would you be interesting in contributing a section? Thanks

Comment: What is `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True`? :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell: No.

It can READ partitioned data but nothing related to writing.

There are several places which document the writing functions and none of them take partition options.

[Can pyarrow write multiple parquet files to a folder like fastparquet's file_scheme='hive' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482434/can-pyarrow-write-multiple-parquet-files-to-a-folder-like-fastparquets-file-sch)

https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/parquet.py#L941

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1858