# Pyarrow gcsfs write_to_dataset

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pyarrow

How do you write to dataset using pyarrow for gcsfs?

I saw a similar issue using s3fs that seems to work: [Pyarrow s3fs partition by timetsamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085686/pyarrow-s3fs-partition-by-timetsamp)

I tried

```
import os
import gcsfs
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

data = {'date': ['2018-03-04T14:12:15.653Z', '2018-03-03T14:12:15.653Z', '2018-03-02T14:12:15.653Z', '2018-03-05T14:12:15.653Z'],
        'battles': [34, 25, 26, 57],
        'citys': ['london', 'newyork', 'boston', 'boston']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'battles', 'citys'])
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"))
df['year'], df['month'], df['day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year), df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month), df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
df.groupby(by=['citys'])

gcs_bucket_name = '<my bucket name>'
GCP_Project_Name = '<my project name>'
fs_gcs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=GCP_Project_Name,token='browser')

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

pq.write_to_dataset(table, 'gcs://test_bucket_python/dataset_name', filesystem=fs_gcs, partition_cols=['year', 'month', 'day'],compression='snappy')
```

I get `OSError: Unrecognized filesystem: <class 'gcsfs.core.GCSFileSystem'>`

Note that `fs_gcs.ls(test_bucket_python)` works, so I know I'm connected to the bucket correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that pyarrow requires a `pyarrow.filesystem.FileSystem` in this use, so would require the equivalent of `pyarrow.filesystem.S3FSWrapper` for GCS.

Since [this PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20729) (not yet released), pandas has started to support GCS at least for reading.

However, dask.dataframe's `to_parquet` does recognise `'gcs://'` for writing, via the fastparquet engine or you can use your `fs_gcs` instance with [fastparquet directly](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystems.html#backend-file-systems), so these are possible options; unless you are happy to write locally and then upload the files.